# Multiple countdown timers generated by template literals (javascript) - contdowns are blinking and all of them print the same remaining time

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

I'm Currently working on a project that requires multiple timers in the same page

They all print the same amount of remaining time despite the differences between the end time of each timer

Is there anyone who can identify what mistake i did

Thank you

here is the JS code:

```js
const posts = [{
    title: 'Countdown 1',
    endTime: 'oct 12 2021 22:10:59 GMT+0200'
  },
  {
    title: 'Countdown 2',
    endTime: 'sep 30 2021 13:59:59 GMT+0200'
  },
  {
    title: 'Countdown 3',
    endTime: 'sep 25 2021 16:59:59 GMT+0200'
  }
];

// *********  the Timer function:  *********
function getRemainingTime(endTime) {
  const total = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  const seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  const hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  const days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return {
    total,
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(endTime) {
  function updateClock() {
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    const t = getRemainingTime(endTime);

    for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
      const daysSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('di');
      const hoursSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('ho');
      const minutesSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('mi');
      const secondsSpan = document.getElementsByClassName('se');

      daysSpan[i].innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2) + ' DAY(S)';
      hoursSpan[i].innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2) + ' HR(S)';
      minutesSpan[i].innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2) + ' MIN(S)';
      secondsSpan[i].innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2) + ' SEC(S)';
    }

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "The countdown is over!"
    }
  }
  updateClock();
  const timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

// *********  the end of the Timer function:  *********    

// *********  the view function using javascript template literals:  ********* 
function postsItem(post) {

  return `<section>
            <h2 class="article-ttitle">${post.title}</h2>
            <article>
                <div id="counter" onload="${initializeClock(post.endTime)}">
                    <span class="di"></span>
                    <span class="ho"></span>
                    <span class="mi"></span>
                    <span class="se"></span>
                <div>
            </article>
        </section>`
}

document.getElementById('posts').innerHTML = `${posts.map(postsItem).join('')}`
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="posts"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to use a unique id for each timer in your HTML.

Comment: your timer variables and the overall calculations of what will go into the HTML looks correct, the incorrect part is how you are adding your results into the HTML. I highly recommend you split up your logic into three functions so it is easier to manage and test: 1) input, 2) processing, 3) output. In part 2) processing, your output will be `t`, return `t` and use it in your 3) output function. Your issue is from updating all three `sections` together, you should update each section manually, assign each one a unique `id`, then update each span individually there. KISS principle, welcome to SO